# Вывод счетчика товаров

Tags: php, функции, циклы

Есть анонимная функция по выводу товаров и их наименованию: *наименование, старая цена и т.д.*

```
$upsells = ['Наименование товара №1_~-250$_~-99$', 'Наименование товара №2_~-699$_~-399$', 'Наименование товара №3_~-299$_~-149$',];
       
$enumerationGoods = function($upsells) {
            
    $productInformation = explode('_~-', $upsells);
    $numberProduct .= '<b>Товар №</b> '.($number += 1).':<br />';
    $orderDetails = ['Наименование', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'];
                            
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($productInformation); $i++) {
        $nomination .= '<b>'.$orderDetails[$i].':</b> '.$productInformation[$i].'<br />';
    }                   
    return $numberProduct . $nomination;
};
$orderTable = array_map($enumerationGoods, $upsells);
echo implode('', $orderTable);
```

Результат

```
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №1
Старая цена: 250$
Новая цена: 99$
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №2
Старая цена: 699$
Новая цена: 399$
Товар № 1:
Наименование: Наименование товара №3
Старая цена: 299$
Новая цена: 149$
```

Как исправить работу счетчика товаров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что анонимная функция (как и обычная функция) **не имеет понятия** о том, какие переменные находятся вне её области видимости.

Поэтому `$number` каждый раз определяется заново нулем и прибавляя единицу получается `1`.

Для прокидывания в анонимную функцию нужных значений используется конструкция `use`, а с учетом того, что переменная будет увеличиваться - передавать ее надо по ссылке:

```
$number = 0;
$enumerationGoods = function() use (&$number) {
    $number += 1;
    echo $number;
};
$enumerationGoods();  // 1
$enumerationGoods();  // 2
$enumerationGoods();  // 3
```

Стоит также открыть и почитать [мануал](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php) (**пример 3**).

Comment: Офигеть ответ, спасибо!) Я не понимал, что означает `use` в функциях написанных кем то. Теперь догадываюсь, до понимания надо еще примеров 15-ть разобрать. Еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, не понимаю, зачем в этом примере вы используете анонимную функцию, если в итоге вам нужно заполнить переменную html с таблицей...

В этом случае, как уже ответили, либо использовать `use` для передачи переменной в функцию, либо пойти другим путем и просто перебрать ваш массив в обычном цикле:

```
$upsells = ['Наименование товара №1_~-250$_~-99$', 'Наименование товара №2_~-699$_~-399$', 'Наименование товара №3_~-299$_~-149$',];

$orderTable = '';
$orderDetails = ['Наименование', 'Старая цена', 'Новая цена'];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($upsells); $i++) {
    $orderTable .= '<b>Товар №</b> '.($i + 1).':<br />';
    $productInformation = explode('_~-', $upsells[$i]);
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($productInformation); $k++) {
        $orderTable .= '<b>'.$orderDetails[$k].':</b> '.$productInformation[$k].'<br />';
    }
}

echo $orderTable;
```

Comment: Этот вопрос продолжения моего вопроса о отправке письма на почту. В тело письма нельзя было просто вставить цикл. Нужно было как то все манипуляциями данных с массивов поместить в одну переменную, и вставить в тело письма.

Comment: Ваше решение так же мне подходит. Спасибо! Еще хотел победить начатое мной решение через анонимную функцию, ведь результат её работы помещается в переменную, поэтому выбрал данное направление.  Теперь у меня два отличных решения, что может быть лучше

Comment: Не за что, главное, что вы разобрались ) Честно говоря, все равно не понимаю. Вот сейчас в переменной `$orderTable` у меня лежит готовый html, эту переменную и вставлять в `$mailer->html()` или как там...  Ну да ладно, тут вам виднее, как говорится, не буду вмешиваться =)

Comment: Вы все правильно пишите) Сейчас впитываю всю информацию, учусь. Мне ума не хватило циклами все скомпоновать в одну переменную. Вспомнил, что неделю назад разбирался с анонимными функциями, что-то там присваивалось переменной, вот и выбрал этот вариант. Понял, что ничего я неделю назад не понял=)